# Does a dual Filipino American citizen need a shore pass to transit Narita/Haneda?

Tags: transit-visas, japan

I have a connecting flight at Narita Airport and will transit to Haneda.  Do I need shore pass? And where can I get a form to get shore pass?

Comment: I believe Japan doesn't issue any tourist/transit visas at this time, and all foreigners are required to have visas to enter.

Comment: I am curious why the airline sold the flight. In 2020 I tried to buy an Air Canada flight with a similar connection and the agent wouldn't sell it to me because the transit was not possible due to covid restrictions.

Comment: @KateGregory While the OP uses the words"connecting flight," the itinerary may well be on two separate tickets.

Comment: @KateGregory Airlines have been overall rather unhelpful to make COVID travel restrictions easy to understand for passengers. They often don't care if the passenger can't take a flight.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica ANA will sell it to you on the same ticket I believe.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Until we hear from the OP, we're guessing.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica true but won't make any difference. OP won't reach their destination unless traveling sometime in the future when Japanese travel restrictions are further relaxed. Or perhaps via https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/173992/1810

Answer (score 3):

> I  have a connecting flight at Narita Airport and will transit to Haneda.

Currently not possible for the vast majority of individuals, because of covid restrictions, unless one has some Japanese visa/passport/some other exceptions allowing entry to Japan. ([Source](https://www.ana.co.jp/asw/topinfo/info_branch_g.jsp?infoID=us_e20220423084413&info_tool_flag=1)). FYI: [Is it possible to enter Japan for a few hours with a group travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/173992/1810)

Comment: Can you provide a source for your statement, because various sites (EG JAL and Haneda itself) talk about Narita/Haneda transfers being possible.

Comment: @PeterM eg https://www.ana.co.jp/asw/topinfo/info_branch_g.jsp?infoID=us_e20220423084413&info_tool_flag=1

Comment: I have seen that page before and IMHO the key clause is "foreign nationals arriving prohibited countries will not be allowed to enter Japan".  That does not explicitly equate "vast majority of individuals" as per your answer.

Comment: @PeterM the key is "the following cases require entry into Japan". The vast majority of individuals will have a very hard time entering Japan with the current entry restrictions, unless they have strong ties with Japan.

Comment: That link says that you need to enter Japan in order to make a transfer between Narita and Haneda. In no way does it say that you need strong ties to Japan in order to make such a transfer. Nor does it imply that some vast number of people can't make such a transfer.

Comment: @PeterM correct, one would have to look at the entry requirements.